# Scala Stream.grouped buffers entire stream into memory

Tags: scala, stream, scala-collections, scala-streams

Calling `grouped` on a Scala `Stream` seems to buffer the entire stream into memory. I've dug in quite a bit here to determine which class is holding the reference to Stream's head.

A simple example:

```
lazy val stream1: Stream[Int] = {
  def loop(v: Int): Stream[Int] = v #:: loop(v + 1)
  loop(0)
}

stream1.take(1000).grouped(10).foreach(println)
```

If one runs this code and places a breakpoint within the `foreach` function, one can see that there is a reference being held to the Stream's head as it's drawn out.

After several iterations, there are still references to earlier "chunks" of the Stream in memory:
[image: Stream Cons in memory after a few iteration]

Additionally, if we inspect the reference to the head of the Stream, we can see that some lambda within IterableLike is holding a reference.

[image]

When `grouped` is called on the `Stream`, the Collections library first calls `iterator` on the `Stream`, returning a [`StreamIterator`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.scala#L1042-L1070) and then `grouped` on *that* iterator, returning a [`GroupedIterator`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala#L1102-L1225). The screenshots above suggest that something within `GroupedIterator` seems to be holding onto the head of the Stream, but I cannot determine what.

My question is twofold: 1. Is this expected behavior with Scala Streams? If not, what is happened within the implementation of StreamIterator and GroupedIterator to cause the head of a Stream to be held onto while running `.grouped(N)` on a `Stream`?

Comment: Isn't `stream1`, which is a `val`, holding on to the head? What happens if there is no `stream1`, i.e. `loop(0).take(....` etc.?

Comment: @jwvh: `object Foo {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Stream.continually(0)
    .grouped(100)
    .zipWithIndex.foreach{
      case (x,i) => 
      if (i % 100 == 0) 
        println(System.currentTimeMillis + " " + i)
    }
  }
}` also just freezes after a while.

Comment: @jwvh true - the "lazy val" setup is pulled from the Stream scaladoc itself; it doesn't seem to hold onto head itself (still wrapping my brain around that one a bit too). For completeness, I tried you suggestion like: `loop(0).take(1000).grouped(10).foreach(println)` and still see the same behavior with a breakpoint within that println